# Unable to post a form using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to post the values using AJAX which i am not able to do so, watever may be it is throwing fail.

```
$("#displayInfo").hide();
   var csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrf").value;
   var csrfName = document.getElementById("csrf").getAttribute("name"); 
   var postfrmdata = $('#'+formid).serialize();
   var returnData= $.ajax({
       url: "ReportsSearchResults",
       type: "POST",
       data: postfrmdata,
       dataType: "json",
       beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfName, csrfToken);
      }
    });
    returnData.done(function(res) {
    alert("Pass"+res);
});
returnData.fail(function(data) {
alert("fail"+data);
});
return false;
```

Kindly tell the reason why it is not getting submitted

Comment: i think there is a problem with your URL is it the correct one ??

Comment: Why are you using plain DOM with jQuery?

Comment: What is the return code when you fail the ajax call? is it 404 or something else?

Comment: At what point does it fail? Does the script even fire?

Comment: The script is getting fired and i tried like what Jason had given. Not working

Comment: It is throwing 405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. I think this is what you are looking for (not tested):

```
//If the form is submitted
$('form').submit(function( e ) {
    e.prevenDefault();
    $form = $(this); //Get this form

    //Post ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'), //Get action attribute of the form
        type: "POST",
        data: $form.serialize(), //Serialize the form
        dataType: "json",
        .done(function() { //or success: function() {
                alert( "success" );
        })
        .fail(function() { //or error: function() {
                alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() { //or beforeSend: function() {
                alert( "complete" );
        });
    });
});
```

And a tip: use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox plugin/extension) to test what's going on in the background. It work's great.